# Python3.x: quickest way to replace characters in very large string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace

Let's say I have the following extremely large string using Python3.x, several GB in size and +10 billion characters in length:

```
string1 = "XYZYXZZXYZZXYZYXYXZYXZYXZYZYZXY.....YY"
```

Given its length, this already takes +GB to load into RAM.

I would like to write a function that will replace every `X` with `A`,  `Y` with `B`, and `Z` with `C`. My goal is to make this as quick as possible. Naturally, this should be efficient as well (e.g. there may be some RAM trade-offs I'm not sure about).

The most obvious solution for me is to use the `string` module and `string.replace()`:

```
import string
def replace_characters(input_string):
    new_string = input_string.replace("X", "A").replace("Y", "B").replace("Z", "C")
    return new_string

foo = replace_characters(string1)
print(foo)
```

which outputs

```
'ABCBACCABCCABCBABACBACBACBCBCAB...BB'
```

I worry this is not the most efficient approach, as I'm simultaneously calling three functions at once on such a large data structure.

What is the most efficient solution for a string this large?

Comment: What is the performance the way you do it now?  Do you have reason to believe that it is unsatisfactory in some way?

Comment: @wallyk It's clunky. I think `.replace()` is first passing through the entire string. So, this function is actually three function calls with at least three temporary strings held in memory. It's not terribly efficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more memory efficient method, that will not generate so many temporary strings along the way, would be to use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

```
>>> string1 = "XYZYXZZXYZZXYZYXYXZYXZYXZYZYZXY"
>>> string1.translate({ord("X"): "A", ord("Y"): "B", ord("Z"): "C"})
'ABCBACCABCCABCBABACBACBACBCBCAB'
```

This will allocate just one (extra large in your case) string.

Comment: Oh, didn't know about this one.

Comment: @Coldspeed Should be a *lot* faster than a regex I'd expect!

Comment: Whoah! Excellent solution

Comment: or, you could just read the entire data into an array (https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) and then convert the specific bytes in the array. No need to allocate another huge buffer.