# Efficient way of multiple replace in large string

Tags: python, string

I want to join multiple sets of characters iteratively in a string. Example:

```py
mystr = 'T h i s _ i s _ a _ s e n t e n c e'
joins = [('e', 'n'), ('en', 't'), ('i', 's'), ('h', 'is')]

# do multiple replace
for bigram in joins:
  mystr = mystr.replace(' '.join(bigram), ''.join(bigram))
print(mystr)
'T his _ is _ a _ s ent en c e'
```

In the first iteration it joins `e n` into `en`, then `en t` into `ent` and so on. It's important that the joins are done in order, since the join ('en', 't') doens't work unless ('e', 'n') has been joined.

With a string of 20MB and 10k joins, this takes a while. I'm looking to optimize this, but I don't know how. Some of the things I've discarded:

- I didn't use regex like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742810/speed-up-millions-of-regex-replacements-in-python-3/42747503#42747503) because I don't know how to do `re.sub` where the substitution is the match itself but joined together
- I didn't use `str.translate` like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44742930/4569908) either because as far as I know, translate can only translate single characters, and in my `joins` there are multiple

Is there any algorithm, string or regex or any other function that would allow me to do this? Thank you!

Comment: It looks that your code actually removes spaces (' ') and nothing more. If this is the case, why don't you just work directly on spaces?

Comment: Are you trying this? `mystr.replace(' ','').replace('_',' ')`

Comment: @IoaTzimas yes it removes spaces but only the ones around the bigrams, not all spaces

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way would be:

```
mystr = 'T h i s _ i s _ a _ s e n t e n c e'

bigrams = [('e', 'n'), ('en', 't'), ('i', 's'), ('h', 'is')]
for first_part, second_part in bigrams:
    mystr = mystr.replace(first_part + ' ' + second_part, first_part + second_part)
print(mystr)
```

Prints:

```
T his _ is _ a _ s ent en c e
```

A second way:

```
mystr = 'T h i s _ i s _ a _ s e n t e n c e'

bigrams = [('e', 'n'), ('en', 't'), ('i', 's'), ('h', 'is')]
for bigram in bigrams:
    mystr = mystr.replace(' '.join(bigram), ''.join(bigram))
print(mystr)
```

You would have to benchmark the two approaches.

Comment: isn't this exactly what I've done? with the option of either getting the tuple wholly or each item individually, bit it's the same thing right?

Comment: Yes. But what you need to do is to take a subset of your bigrams and/or a smaller string and benchmark the two ways of doing the replace and see which one performs better.

Comment: thank you, I tried and your first approach is slightly slower than the one I've done. My idea/goal was that there would be a way to bypass the loop and do all the replacements in one place, but it seems like the loop is unavoidable